# in_array unexpected results

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I have an array that looks likes this,

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 40's
    [1] =>  50's
    [2] =>  60's
)
```

and some code that looks like this,

```
<?php if(isset($playable_age) && in_array('40\'s', $playable_age)) { $set = TRUE; } else { $set = FALSE; } ?>
<div class="checkbox"><?php echo $this->formbuilder->checkbox( 'playable_age[]', "40's", "40's", $set ); ?></div>
<?php if(isset($playable_age) && in_array('50\'s', $playable_age)) { $set = TRUE; } else { $set = FALSE; } ?>
<div class="checkbox"><?php echo $this->formbuilder->checkbox( 'playable_age[]', "50's", "50's", $set ); ?></div>
<?php if(isset($playable_age) && in_array('60\'s', $playable_age)) { $set = TRUE; } else { $set = FALSE; } ?>
<div class="checkbox"><?php echo $this->formbuilder->checkbox( 'playable_age[]', "60's", "60's", $set ); ?></div>
```

Now the first if statement returns true, however the 2nd and 3rd if return false even though the 50's and 60's values exist in the array why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there is a space before these values in the array:

```
[1] =>  50's
[2] =>  60's
       ^
```

Something not seen with the first value:

```
[0] => 40's
```

Comment: This is probably why we wanna store them as ints... xD

Comment: It's worth noting that `var_dump()` provides more accurate data than `print_r()`.

Comment: how this array is made?,if possible trim values before inserting in to array.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a syntax error.

You can do this:

```
<?php 
$playable_age = array(0=>'40\'s',1=>'50\'s',2=>'60\'s');
if(isset($playable_age) && in_array('40\'s', $playable_age)) { $set = TRUE; echo "1"; } else { $set = FALSE; echo "2"; } 
if(isset($playable_age) && in_array('50\'s', $playable_age)) { $set = TRUE; echo "3"; } else { $set = FALSE; echo "4"; } 
if(isset($playable_age) && in_array('60\'s', $playable_age)) { $set = TRUE; echo "5"; } else { $set = FALSE; echo "6"; } 
if(isset($playable_age) && in_array('70\'s', $playable_age)) { $set = TRUE; echo "7"; } else { $set = FALSE; echo "8"; } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you perform logic checks on the array, create a user-defined function and call it with array_walk to trim() on each array value.